# KafkaTemplate Producer error unwanted red highlighting using Intellij

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, apache-kafka

I'm using Intellij to run a springboot app using Kafka. I am new to java and kafka so please bare with me. The problem might be Intellij I'm not sure but the line with
--- kafkaTemplate.send("t_hello" + name);-- Is under lined red and when i hover over it i get this message "Cannot resolve method 'send(java.lang.String)" Does anyone know how to get rid of the Darn Red underline. The app does not send the the message, it just gives me a red line error that I cant get rid of. The bottom of the output should have the message Hello Timotius and a random number

```
package com.course.kafkaproducer.producer;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class HelloKafkaProducer {

    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate;
    public void sendHello(String name) {
        kafkaTemplate.send("t_hello" + name);
    }
}
```

```
package com.course.kafkaproducer;

import com.course.kafkaproducer.producer.HelloKafkaProducer;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class KafkaProducerApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private HelloKafkaProducer helloKafkaProducer;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(KafkaProducerApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        helloKafkaProducer.sendHello("Timotius" + Math.random());
    }
}
```

The POM

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.course</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-producer</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>kafka-producer</name>
    <description>Kafka producer</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>14</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

the out put is:

```
com.course.kafkaconsumer.KafkaConsumerApplication
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Options -Xverify:none and -noverify were deprecated in JDK 13 and will likely be removed in a future release.

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.3.1.RELEASE)

2020-06-27 18:25:08.418  INFO 73588 --- [           main] c.c.k.KafkaConsumerApplication           : Starting KafkaConsumerApplication on justins-MacBook-Pro-2.local with PID 73588 (/Users/justinmeskan/Downloads/kafkaJustin/kafka-consumer/target/classes started by justinmeskan in /Users/justinmeskan/Downloads/kafkaJustin)
2020-06-27 18:25:08.420  INFO 73588 --- [           main] c.c.k.KafkaConsumerApplication           : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-06-27 18:25:09.502  INFO 73588 --- [           main] o.a.k.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig    : ConsumerConfig values: 
    allow.auto.create.topics = true
    auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000
    auto.offset.reset = latest
    bootstrap.servers = [localhost:9092]
    check.crcs = true
    client.dns.lookup = default
    client.id = 
    client.rack = 
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    default.api.timeout.ms = 60000
    enable.auto.commit = false
    exclude.internal.topics = true
    fetch.max.bytes = 52428800
    fetch.max.wait.ms = 500
    fetch.min.bytes = 1
    group.id = default-spring-consumer
    group.instance.id = null
    heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000
    interceptor.classes = []
    internal.leave.group.on.close = true
    isolation.level = read_uncommitted
    key.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
    max.partition.fetch.bytes = 1048576
    max.poll.interval.ms = 300000
    max.poll.records = 500
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    metric.reporters = []
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    metrics.recording.level = INFO
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    partition.assignment.strategy = [class org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor]
    receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
    reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    request.timeout.ms = 30000
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.jaas.config = null
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.login.class = null
    sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
    sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
    sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
    security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
    security.providers = null
    send.buffer.bytes = 131072
    session.timeout.ms = 10000
    ssl.cipher.suites = null
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2]
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
    ssl.key.password = null
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    ssl.keystore.location = null
    ssl.keystore.password = null
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    ssl.protocol = TLSv1.2
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    ssl.truststore.location = null
    ssl.truststore.password = null
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS
    value.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer

2020-06-27 18:25:09.579  INFO 73588 --- [           main] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka version: 2.5.0
2020-06-27 18:25:09.581  INFO 73588 --- [           main] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka commitId: 66563e712b0b9f84
2020-06-27 18:25:09.581  INFO 73588 --- [           main] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka startTimeMs: 1593307509575
2020-06-27 18:25:09.586  INFO 73588 --- [           main] o.a.k.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer     : [Consumer clientId=consumer-default-spring-consumer-1, groupId=default-spring-consumer] Subscribed to topic(s): t_hello
2020-06-27 18:25:09.588  INFO 73588 --- [           main] o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler          : Initializing ExecutorService
2020-06-27 18:25:09.605  INFO 73588 --- [           main] c.c.k.KafkaConsumerApplication           : Started KafkaConsumerApplication in 1.691 seconds (JVM running for 2.803)
2020-06-27 18:25:10.123  INFO 73588 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata        : [Consumer clientId=consumer-default-spring-consumer-1, groupId=default-spring-consumer] Cluster ID: Xyqqb0-GSmeTFFgfgPfuGw
2020-06-27 18:25:10.130  INFO 73588 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-default-spring-consumer-1, groupId=default-spring-consumer] Discovered group coordinator 127.0.0.1:9092 (id: 2147483646 rack: null)
2020-06-27 18:25:10.139  INFO 73588 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-default-spring-consumer-1, groupId=default-spring-consumer] (Re-)joining group
2020-06-27 18:25:10.196  INFO 73588 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-default-spring-consumer-1, groupId=default-spring-consumer] Join group failed with org.apache.kafka.common.errors.MemberIdRequiredException: The group member needs to have a valid member id before actually entering a consumer group
2020-06-27 18:25:10.196  INFO 73588 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-default-spring-consumer-1, groupId=default-spring-consumer] (Re-)joining group
2020-06-27 18:25:10.221  INFO 73588 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-default-spring-consumer-1, groupId=default-spring-consumer] Finished assignment for group at generation 1: {consumer-default-spring-consumer-1-d7748fca-38eb-4a75-97fc-64c0b145d290=Assignment(partitions=[t_hello-0])}
2020-06-27 18:25:10.241  INFO 73588 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-default-spring-consumer-1, groupId=default-spring-consumer] Successfully joined group with generation 1
2020-06-27 18:25:10.245  INFO 73588 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-default-spring-consumer-1, groupId=default-spring-consumer] Adding newly assigned partitions: t_hello-0
2020-06-27 18:25:10.257  INFO 73588 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-default-spring-consumer-1, groupId=default-spring-consumer] Found no committed offset for partition t_hello-0
2020-06-27 18:25:10.269  INFO 73588 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-default-spring-consumer-1, groupId=default-spring-consumer] Found no committed offset for partition t_hello-0
2020-06-27 18:25:10.294  INFO 73588 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.SubscriptionState    : [Consumer clientId=consumer-default-spring-consumer-1, groupId=default-spring-consumer] Resetting offset for partition t_hello-0 to offset 0.
2020-06-27 18:25:10.314  INFO 73588 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : default-spring-consumer: partitions assigned: [t_hello-0]
2020-06-27 18:27:43.424  INFO 73588 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-default-spring-consumer-1, groupId=default-spring-consumer] Attempt to heartbeat failed since coordinator 127.0.0.1:9092 (id: 2147483646 rack: null) is either not started or not valid
2020-06-27 18:27:43.424  INFO 73588 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-default-spring-consumer-1, groupId=default-spring-consumer] Group coordinator 127.0.0.1:9092 (id: 2147483646 rack: null) is unavailable or invalid, will attempt rediscovery
2020-06-27 18:27:45.152  INFO 73588 --- [spring-consumer] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-default-spring-consumer-1, groupId=default-spring-consumer] Discovered group coordinator 127.0.0.1:9092 (id: 2147483646 rack: null)
2020-06-27 18:27:45.166  INFO 73588 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-default-spring-consumer-1, groupId=default-spring-consumer] Attempt to heartbeat failed for since member id consumer-default-spring-consumer-1-d7748fca-38eb-4a75-97fc-64c0b145d290 is not valid.
2020-06-27 18:27:45.167  INFO 73588 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-default-spring-consumer-1, groupId=default-spring-consumer] Giving away all assigned partitions as lost since generation has been reset,indicating that consumer is no longer part of the group
2020-06-27 18:27:45.167  INFO 73588 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-default-spring-consumer-1, groupId=default-spring-consumer] Lost previously assigned partitions t_hello-0
2020-06-27 18:27:45.167  INFO 73588 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : default-spring-consumer: partitions lost: [t_hello-0]
2020-06-27 18:27:45.167  INFO 73588 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : default-spring-consumer: partitions revoked: [t_hello-0]
2020-06-27 18:27:45.168  INFO 73588 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-default-spring-consumer-1, groupId=default-spring-consumer] (Re-)joining group
2020-06-27 18:27:45.174  INFO 73588 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-default-spring-consumer-1, groupId=default-spring-consumer] Join group failed with org.apache.kafka.common.errors.MemberIdRequiredException: The group member needs to have a valid member id before actually entering a consumer group
2020-06-27 18:27:45.175  INFO 73588 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-default-spring-consumer-1, groupId=default-spring-consumer] (Re-)joining group
2020-06-27 18:27:45.183  INFO 73588 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-default-spring-consumer-1, groupId=default-spring-consumer] Finished assignment for group at generation 1: {consumer-default-spring-consumer-1-9449779f-5ce7-4139-8bf8-20ddfb75e8f7=Assignment(partitions=[t_hello-0])}
2020-06-27 18:27:45.190  INFO 73588 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-default-spring-consumer-1, groupId=default-spring-consumer] Successfully joined group with generation 1
2020-06-27 18:27:45.191  INFO 73588 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-default-spring-consumer-1, groupId=default-spring-consumer] Adding newly assigned partitions: t_hello-0
2020-06-27 18:27:45.194  INFO 73588 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-default-spring-consumer-1, groupId=default-spring-consumer] Found no committed offset for partition t_hello-0
2020-06-27 18:27:45.198  INFO 73588 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-default-spring-consumer-1, groupId=default-spring-consumer] Found no committed offset for partition t_hello-0
2020-06-27 18:27:45.656  INFO 73588 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.SubscriptionState    : [Consumer clientId=consumer-default-spring-consumer-1, groupId=default-spring-consumer] Resetting offset for partition t_hello-0 to offset 0.
2020-06-27 18:27:45.670  INFO 73588 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : default-spring-consumer: partitions assigned: [t_hello-0]
```

Comment: seems like there is no `send` method with one argument https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/core/KafkaTemplate.html

Comment: Yes I believe your right Intellij had a lot of options and the tutorial Didn't say which one to use

Comment: Thanks for all the help guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the topic name as well where you want to send the message.

```
 kafkaTemplate.send(topicName, msg);
```

Hope you have done the broker configuration already because kafka doesn't know you broker address already unless you specify it. Something like this.

```
 @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
        configProps.put(
          ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, 
          bootstrapAddress);
        configProps.put(
          ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, 
          StringSerializer.class);
        configProps.put(
          ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, 
          StringSerializer.class);
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configProps);
    }
 
    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
    }
```

Comment: Thanks you, the adding the topic to send helped thanks. I am just learning Kafka so I'm going through a Udemy tutorial and I have not heard anything about the broker yet..lol I It's a single node kafka tutorial. Can you expand on the broker part of your anwser please Thank You so much..

Comment: there are many websites available to give a basic understanding. e g. https://www.cloudkarafka.com/blog/2016-11-30-part1-kafka-for-beginners-what-is-apache-kafka.html

Comment: Great link once again you've made this transfer of knowledge a bit smoother

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes the IntelliJ config messes up.
Delete the .idea folder and import it with

File -> New Project from existing sources

and select Maven.

That means select the same project you are in...

Go through the wizard and done.

Comment: This wasn't the issue but thank you for the help I was stuck for a minute

Answer (score 1):

I ended up separating the producer and the consumer into two different projects. The tutorial had said to import them both into Eclipse but I use Intellij. After that, I used part of @rahulP answer to set the topic in the 'producers.send' method. I had to make sure that IntelliJ selected the right type, then you have to select the send method that takes a topic and message argument. Once I ran both of the apps separately and got the message sent through the red lines Intellij had put under the "helloKafkaProducer" and "helloKafkaProducer.sendHello("Timotius" + Math.random())" just disappeared.

Comment: Delete the .idea directory/folder and reopen the project worked for me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with IntelliJ and Kafka. I was also following along with a Udemy tutorial and the instructor left out a lot of the versions and actual types that needed to be applied to different variables. He was using Eclipse and I was using IntelliJ. I had to go back and carefully check every type i selected. After the first time the Kafka ran successfully all the red error lines disappeared. I hope this helps anyone learning Kafka.

Comment: Ya, that's basically the jist of it, I sounds like we may have bumped into the same teacher on Udemy it's hit or miss. You guys all did a great job answering this question